# Rails > Spree Commerce: Get requests not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have followed the spree setup instructions as mentioned on its [github](https://github.com/spree/spree) page.

After receiving the message: `Spree has been installed successfully. You're all ready to go! Enjoy` I started the application on my localhost.

Now when I tried accessing it on `http://192.168.15.164:3000/` the browser just returns `This webpage is not available` and there is no processing for get requests in the log which is supposed to happen whenever a page is requested.

The only logs that were generated was that of application boot:

```
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    [2015-01-22 10:38:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2015-01-22 10:38:05] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
    [2015-01-22 10:38:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22152 port=3000
```

There is one thing that seemed strange in these logs. Usually my applications are started on `http://0.0.0.0:3000` and i access them with the ip `http://192.168.15.164:3000/`. But the spree app was started on `http://localhost:3000`. I tried accessing with this address as well but no luck.

This is how my application boot log usually looks like:

```
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.1.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    [2015-01-22 10:39:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2015-01-22 10:39:00] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
    [2015-01-22 10:39:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22237 port=3000
```

Can anyone point out what exactly am I missing here? Goggling didn't help much for this particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out shortly after posting this question. Here is what I did in case someone else finds him/herself in a similar situation.

The problem was that the application was getting started on the wrong address `localhost:3000`. This was what hinted me to try to deliberately start it with the exact ip and port combination. So I mentioned them along in the rails server command like so:

`rails server -b 192.168.15.164 -p 3000`

And it worked like a charm :)